# Weird issue: UITableViewCell would not detect touch although it's accessory view does

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a very simple `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCell` in it. `DataSource` and `Delegates` are correctly set up. It shows data correctly. But the tableview's cell is not responding to touch. **Although cell's accessory view does respond to touch**.

I tried creating segues for both cell and cell's accesory view. Only the segue connected to accessory view works. (Also `didSelectRowAtIndex` path method wouldn't get called)

What could be the reason, and how to debug an issue like this?

Comment: are you using any `button` inside your `custom cell`

Comment: no , it's just a generic cell not even a custom cell

Comment: does data loads correctly to the cells. if you don't mind could you please put your implementation of tableview delegate methods.

Comment: Yes data loads correctly. No delegate methods implemented, just a segue to another view from the cell. However I tested with delegates implemented as well, since no touches received, delegate methods also won't get called (on cell's contentView). However delegates and segues works when I tap it's accessory view. So it's not a problem with delegate or datasource.  Problem is  cell's content view not receiving touches.

Comment: which iOS version are you using

Comment: @AnuradhS iOS 9.3 and also tested with 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The reason why UITableViewCell was not detecting touches was, I had a tap gesture recognizer added to the view and, even when I tap on the cell, this tap gesture even would fire and cancel out any other events. To avoid that following line needed to be added.

**Swift**

```
 tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

**Objective-C**

```
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

there might be several issues here, what I should do is:

1: Make sure that the cell can be selected (`tableView.allowsSelection = true`)

2: in your delegate, add the

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

(be careful that you do not add the "didDeSelect" method :-))

method; add a breakpoint in there to see if it receives touches

that is what I would check, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried every possible solution to get this work. None of these work. As I mentioned in the question title, it does not detects any touches but accessory view does receive touches.  Problem is indeed not receiving touches, even though every possible thing that can go wrong was correctly set up and double checked.

Answer (score 1):

@Rukshan's answer is correct for me. It fixed my issue of the conflict of the pan gesture and UITableView events.

In my case, I have multiple layers of nested scrollviews/tableviews to implement as some blog apps. The user can scroll the outer scrollview to not only make the scrollview's content view scrolling, but also make the sub tableviews scrolling too.

So I use the pan gesture and disable other scrollview's/tableview's scrolling ability. But after scrolling, the user taps the sub tableview for the first time, it doesn't respond to [tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:] function. The user has to tap twice, then the [tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:] function works.

@Rukshan's answer helps resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, my cell has clear color so only the subviews like labels and images detect taps. 
One solution is to change the background color into black with opacity.

[image]