# Can't get didSelectRowAt to work for TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I am having trouble getting the `didSelectRowAt` method to work for a `TableView` inside of a regular `ViewController`. I have already made sure that the `delegate` and `data source` for the table are set in the `ViewController` code. This `ViewController` populates the `tableview` cells with results from a search query to an **API**, and the rendering of cell data is working fine.

It's just the `didSelectRowAt` method that is not registering. I did try manually adding the same delegate information on the Main.storyboard, but the little **`+`** sign won't trigger any popup windows. I am wondering if there is something in the `Main.storyboard` that needs fixing. I have attached the images of the `ViewController` and `TableView` connections inspector as well. I am new to iOS development and don't have much experience with graphic interfaces for mobile design, so I am assuming it's something there but maybe I am wrong.

Here's the basic version of my code:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

   ...variable declarations ....

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    searchResults = []
    searchBar.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults!.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell

    if(searchActive && !(self.searchResults?.isEmpty)!) {
        (doing some stuff with search results here...works fine)
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  print("hello!")
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
               textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("search text \(searchText)")
    getSearchResultJSON(term: searchText) { json in
        let data = json as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
        self.searchResults = data
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
...
}
```

[[image: Viewcontroller connections inspector]]

[[image: TableView Connections Inspector]]

**EDIT:** as a sanity check for if the search asynchronous function was changing anything, I just tried removing all search-related code and filling the tableview from a hardcoded dummy variable array. It worked to display the dummy variables, but still no ability to select a cell and get any reaction. I also saw a couple mentions that I had previously had a typo with didDeSelectRowAt instead of didSelectRow at, that has been fixed but the behaviour is the same.

This ended up being related to a tap gesture that occurs in the hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() extension that I wrote

Comment: try to remove the delegate declaration in the viewdidload method and set the tableview delegate in the storyboard

Comment: HAve you taken any tapgesture or button over table cell?

Comment: You are using didDeselectRowAt method.

Comment: great catch @Niharkia ! however I fixed this and the issue still persists

Comment: @Mr.Bista no, no tapgestures or buttons, although I realize that this could have been the issue if so

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan I just tried that thanks - however the add button to add the delegate in the storyboard is greyed out

Comment: you have set "UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate" for your tableview

Comment: @Birendra thanks, I thought this was standard? What should it be instead?

Comment: it is use to call built in method of tableview

Comment: like this tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: @Birendra hm, you will see that I have already done that in viewDidLoad() above.

Comment: can you give your code file so i can check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird issue: UITableViewCell would not detect touch although it's accessory view does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744406/weird-issue-uitableviewcell-would-not-detect-touch-although-its-accessory-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! The culprit was the `self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()`, which is an extension I wrote to hide the keyboard. This interfered with the tap of a cell because it did indeed utilize `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Thanks for the hints everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `didDeselectRowAt` instead of `didSelectRowAt`

**Edit**

Well, use this below delegate then

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and make your controller conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Comment: I wish I could say this was the answer because it makes perfect sense! But I just made that edit and the cell is still not responding to selection

Comment: You cannot see "hello" printed when clicking the cell?

Comment: Nope, no printed message @Matt

Comment: as a sanity check for if the search asynchronous function was changing anything, I just tried filling the tableview from a hardcoded dummy variable array. It worked to display the dummy variables, but still no ability to select a cell and get any reaction

Comment: can you comment everything about search bar and check again with just tableview in your view?

Comment: thanks, @Matt yep, just tried that. I removed all the Search-related code, still no reaction on didSelectRowAt

Comment: I tried your code only with table view and it worked flawlessly. Do you have anything that might block cell interactions? Can you scroll your table?

Comment: Thanks again @Matt. I can scroll the table, yes. Is that a problem? I can also long press to make the cell appear grey, although it goes back to white when I release it

Comment: are you using any gestures like tap, pan?

Comment: Yes! Found it. UITapGestureRecognizer is used in the extension I wrote to hide the keyboard, called with self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround(). Fixing this method remedied the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tap gesture on main view then table view cell did select method is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In picture you uploaded, delegate and datasource aren't connected to the ViewController. 
Remove the code in viewdidload (tableview.delegate = self) and connect them in storyboard.